# Concatenate []byte and hash

Tags: go

I have something like

```
unixtime := time.Now().Unix()

unixtimeStr := string(unixtime)

soup := make([]byte, len(data) + len(nonce) + len(unixtimeStr) + len(previousHash))

copy(soup[:], data)
copy(soup[len(data):], nonce)
copy(soup[len(data) + len(nonce):], []byte(unixtimeStr))
copy(soup[len(data) + len(nonce) + len(unixtimeStr):], previousHash)

hasher := sha1.New()
hasher.Write(soup)
var hash []byte = hasher.Sum(nil)
```

`data`, `nonce`, `previousHash` are of type `[]byte`.

I find it so dirty and unreadable!

I'd like a more object oriented coding style like

```
soup := data.concat(nonce).concat([]byte(unixtimeStr)).concat(previousHash)
```

or at least something like

```
soup := concat(data, nonce, ...)
```

How would you write this snippet?

Comment: `soup = append(soup, nonce...)` etc

Comment: Thanks, use it like this now: `soup := append(data, append(nonce, append([]byte(strconv.FormatInt(unixtime, 10)), previousHash...)...)...)` Can still imagine prettier code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example,

```
var data, nonce, previousHash []byte

unixtime := strconv.FormatInt(time.Now().Unix(), 10)
hasher := sha1.New()
hasher.Write(data)
hasher.Write(nonce)
hasher.Write([]byte(unixtime))
hasher.Write(previousHash)
hash := hasher.Sum(nil)
```

Or,

```
var data, nonce, previousHash []byte

unixtime := strconv.FormatInt(time.Now().Unix(), 10)
soup := make([]byte, 0, len(data)+len(nonce)+len(unixtime)+len(previousHash))
soup = append(soup, data...)
soup = append(soup, nonce...)
soup = append(soup, unixtime...)
soup = append(soup, previousHash...)
hasher := sha1.New()
hasher.Write(soup)
hash := hasher.Sum(nil)
```

---

Note:

```
unixtime := time.Now().Unix()
unixtimeStr := string(unixtime)
```

is nonsensical. It's always the Unicode replacement character. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "unicode"
)

func main() {
    unixtime := time.Now().Unix()
    unixtimeStr := string(unixtime)
    fmt.Println(unixtimeStr == string(unicode.ReplacementChar))
}
```

Output:

```
true
```

To convert an integer to a string, use the `strconv` package. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    unixtimeStr := strconv.FormatInt(time.Now().Unix(), 10)
    fmt.Println(unixtimeStr)
}
```

Output:

```
1257894000
```

Comment: Okay, so I decided to use it like this: `soup := append(data, append(nonce, append([]byte(strconv.FormatInt(unixtime, 10)), previousHash...)...)...)` It is not beautiful but it does the trick.

Comment: @ChrisPillen: [Go Code Review Comments: Line Length](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#line-length): avoid uncomfortably long lines. Readability is paramount.

Comment: thanks. (If the syntax allowed shorter code the lines would be shorter too )

Comment: @ChrisPillen: Start by shortening the length of your names. [Names](https://research.swtch.com/names): *A name's length should not exceed its information content.*

Comment: That might be what the designers of Go think, good coding style should look like. The truth is, a name should communicate it‘s meaning uniquely in it‘s current context. ˋsoup := data.merge(nonce, unixtime, previousHash)ˋ would do it in a well designed language.

Answer (score 0):

I should point out that `hash.Hash` is an `io.Writer` so you can pass it as the first argument to `fmt.Fprintf(...)` -- and, since `fmt` does the *Right Thing* for byte slices with its `%s` verb, you could make this a lot more readable by:

```
h := sha1.New()
fmt.Fprintf(h, "%s%s%d%s", data, nonce, time.Now().Unix(), prev)
```

...and, it takes care of your integer conversion for you too (with the `%d`)

(Obligatory [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/WJ0lrJRgUr4) Link)

Note: `fmt.Fprintf(...)` is not terribly fast; if performance is important you should find another way to do this. Performance and readability are often a delicate balance.

Comment: Performance is important. So that I came up with the `copy` approach.